# Submitting a form in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a template like this:

```
<div><form id="appForm" method="POST" action="{{form.formActionAttr}}">
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="input1" type="hidden" value="{{form.input1}}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="input2" type="hidden" value="{{form.input2}}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form></div>
```

here is the controller:

```
function SamlFormController($scope, $sce, metadataService) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.form.formActionAttr = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('some.url');
    $scope.form.input1 = 'input1';
    $scope.form.input2 = 'input2';

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        document.getElementById('appForm').submit();
    };
    $scope.submitForm();
}
```

Here is my intention:
the controller run the submitForm() method, which send a HTTP POST request to the form.formActionAttr url.

But with the codes above, the action="{{form.formActionAttr}}" is not populated yet when the $scope.submitForm() is called.

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl will return the trusted value in your context so should be instant. How did you check whether it is the target issue or something else?

Comment: @PM. when i run the page, it is redirected to something like: localhost:8080/{{form.formActionAttr}} and saying this page is not found

Comment: Why are you using a view if it's not doing anything, instead of just sending an http request with $http? Also, it's better to reference the form by the `name` attribute. If you set the `name`, it will be available on the scope under that property.

Comment: @CShark Basically I'm implementing a SAML flow. The view that does nothing but sending the POST is the last step of the SAML authorization. In order for Service Provider to set session cookies, I can't use $http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the url will only be set after you application has really initialized. So you need to push the change to a later stage. You can easily do this using the $timeout service:

```
function SamlFormController($scope, $sce, $timeout, metadataService) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.form.formActionAttr = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('some.url');
    $scope.form.input1 = 'input1';
    $scope.form.input2 = 'input2';

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        document.getElementById('appForm').submit();
    };
    $timeout(function() { $scope.submitForm() });
}
```

Comment: The interpolated value in the `action` attribute will be evaluated and filled in after a digest cycle after this controller gets initialized.